# how to add poi library to eclipse rcp project?

Tags: eclipse, apache-poi, eclipse-rcp

i'm trying to debug/run my app with poi libraries.

I added jar files downloaded from [POI Official Site](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.16), and I put it in *lib* folder.
I also configure build path and add manually each one of the jar files.

This are the libraries ...

[image]

NOTE: In my libraries I allready have poi-3.0.1-FINAL.jar.

When I edit the class, i have no errors.
but when I run or debug app, i get this in console:

> java.version=1.6.0_45 java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. BootLoader
>   constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=es_AR Framework arguments:
>   -product AgroTracker.product Command-line arguments:  -product AgroTracker.product -data
>   C:\Users\Nico\AgroTrackerWrkSpace/../runtime-AgroTracker.product -dev
>   file:C:/Users/Nico/AgroTrackerWrkSpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/AgroTracker.product/dev.properties
>   -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-06-28 08:12:55.143 !MESSAGE Unhandled
>   event loop exception !STACK 0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook  at
>   ar.com.cse.cseagro.view.ensayo.CargaEnsayoView$13.widgetSelected(CargaEnsayoView.java:491)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)

What I'm missing to do in eclipse ?

What are the minimum jar files necesary to write and read .XLSX files ?

Best regards!

Binaries !!

[image: POI Binary]

Answer (score 3):

In a plug-in you must add the library jars to the plug-in's classpath rather than just adding them to the build path.

Open the MANIFEST.MF editor. On the 'Runtime' tab look at the 'Classpath' section. Click Add... and add the jars to the class path. Make sure you do not delete the '.' entry. This will add the jars to the 'Bundle-Classpath' in the MANIFEST.MF

On the 'Build' tab add the jars to the 'Binary Build' list. This will update the 'build.properties' file to make sure the files are included in the plug-in when it is built.

Comment: thanks greg, I allready have all the jars below "lib" folder, so when I click on Add..., there is nothing to add. Just in case, I deleted ".\lib" and added again! With no luck :(

Comment: Show us the MANIFEST.MF and the build.properties in your plugin.

Comment: Thanks greg! it was a series of troubles !. The main issue is that i was missing jar files, after that I have to level up, my app, from jre1.5 to jse1.6, and move up poi-ooxml.3.16 before poi.3.01 final (the las one does not include XSSF ! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download [latest version](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)

Step 2: Unzip (unpack) files to what ever directory you want

Step 3: Right-click on you eclipse project in the eclipse package explorer

Step 4: Select Build Path >> Add External Archives...

Step 5: Navigate to the unzipped folder

Step 6: Select all files

Step 7: Click "Open"
[image]

Step 8: Rejoice